# How can I soothe a teething baby that doesn't want anything put in his mouth?

Tags: infant, teething

Our 7 month newborn son recently started teething. Lately it's gotten pretty bad ... to the point where he gets worked up in what seems like mini-anxiety attacks and has a unique cry.

During the day, it doesn't seem as bad if we take him for walks or play. I suspect that's because he has more opportunities to be distracted.  At nighttime though,  it seems worse.  We've tried things like teethers, pacifiers, a cold/frozen rag, etc but at times he just doesn't want anything in his mouth.

Any suggestions for how to help a teething baby under these circumstances and still maintain sanity?

Comment: There might be something either over the counter or by prescription that might provide a bit of numbing, which might be safe to use just at that time of day.  You could check with the doctor or nurse by phone.

Answer (score 2):

If it's really intense then you can consider using child-appropriate pain relievers (acetaminophen or ibuprofen) but, naturally, consult a doctor first.

Orajel is the go-to for 2+ *but not appropriate for a 7 month old* and we never had any success with any of the natural remedies that are available.

With our daughter, when it was worst, her favourite soother was my finger... it hurt but provided some relief although not always enough for her to fall back asleep.

Good luck!